# Custom buttons inside UIWebView (for iPad)

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview

Basically I want to put custom buttons on a UIWeebView.

I have a URL which fetches a PDF file. In that PDF there is a column of "myButton" and I need to put the button on it so that scrolls with the file.

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: you need buttons on webview or on your website ? if from website you would need to add some js code.

Comment: @LalithB  Thanks For Your Comment. I Just need it on My WebView .when I hit the button It takes me to signature View Controller .

Comment: is the content's height(that is are you showing same content on your webview?) and location of your button inside the webview preknown ?

Comment: @LalithB .That is part of  my webView content . I just want to put My button on "customer Signature" column , which as shown above.

Comment: @LalithB Do You know , How to get solution for it .?

Comment: find my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a view to webview's scrollview

```
[webView.scrollView addSubview:youSubView];
```

Set your co-ordinates of the subview according to your requirement. The scrollview can be accessed only > iOS5. Refer the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I will go through it by tomorrow . .

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I achieved it by changing in document itself, by adding some link at document and  in XCODE ""if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"button://"]) "" .